# Histograms: Python matplotlib.bar using for loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

#### Attempt

I tried to plot some histograms in **python3.7** with **matplotlib 3.0.3** and got a problem:

#### Code:

```
ind = np.arange(2)
width = 0.35
data = [(0.5, 0.1), (0.8, 0.3)]
for i in data:
    plt.bar(ind, i[0], width, yerr=i[1])
plt.ylabel('scratchwidth /cm')
plt.show
```

#### Outputs:

I expect a plot with two bars, `(0|0.5)` and `(1|0.8)` with the uncertainties `0.1` and `0.3`. What I get is two bars, both of them with **y=0.8** and an uncertainty of **0.3**. Does `plt.bar()` not work in a for-loop? 
How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must pass an array of Y's and an array of Err's to the function `bar`. Transform your data from an array of points to an array of arrays of Y's and Err's:

```
ind = np.arange(2)
width = 0.35
data = [(0.5, 0.1), (0.8, 0.3)]
y, err = list(zip(*data)) # Transpose the data array
plt.bar(ind, y, width, yerr=err)
plt.ylabel('scratchwidth /cm')
plt.show()
```

Or, since you already use numpy, use a numpy array:

```
....
data = np.array([(0.5, 0.1), (0.8, 0.3)])
plt.bar(ind, data[:,0], width, yerr=data[:,1])
....
```